# Как вернуть картинку в old из созданного валидатора в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно можно получить картинку в созданном реквесте и вернуть ее обратно в old в blade в случае неудачной валидации. Видимо то что я с глобального реквеста добавил в form request изображение этого недостаточно чтобы получить изображение в блейде. При дебаге null всегда возвращается

Валидатор

```html
class UserInfoRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        $this->request->add(['avatar_image' => request()->file('avatar_image')]);

        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'region_id' => 'required|integer',
            'region_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'address' => 'string|max:255',
            'avatar_image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        ];
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
    <div class="form-group profile-settings__avatar">
        <img id="avatar-user" class="rounded-circle" src="{{asset('images/icon/user.svg')}}" />
        @if ($errors->has('avatar_image'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback d-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('avatar_image') }}</strong></span>
        @endif
        <input type="file" id="change-avatar" name="avatar_image" value="{{ old('avatar_image') }}"
               onchange="document.getElementById('avatar-user').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">

        <label for="change-avatar">Изменить аватар</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: К сожалению это невозможно в Laravel-е. Можете читать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158328/laravel-5-1-keep-uploaded-file-as-old-input)

Comment: а какой еще вариант можно придумать? когда в случае неудачной валидаций avatar_image в олде чтобы был? валидация только в контроллере и все больше нету варов?

Comment: Нужно отправить/обработать данные через `ajax` запрос используя javascript @Vlad